# require confirmation before updating ng-model or executing ng-change in angularjs checkbox input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I have a checkbox input that when checked sets `customer.isCompleted` to true or false and saves the customer data through a `firebase api` using `ng-change`

```
input type="checkbox" ng-model="customer.isCompleted" ng-change="sc.data.$save(customer)"
```

however i want to make sure when customer checks the box, it prompts for confirmation. If users hits OK then, it should check the box, update the `ngMode`l and fire `ngChange`otherwise do nothing.(and do this when the box is checked or unchecked). when checked the confirmation box should say message1 and when unchecked it should say message2.

how can I implement this. I'm assuming a directive, but don't know how i'd implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several trial & error i've figured out the code that works. I've expanded upon the $parsers solution from karaxuna. What I'm doing here is checking the $viewValue & $modelValue, correcting viewValue when cancel button is pressed.

```
 return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

    var x = false;

    ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
      if (ngModel.$viewValue === true && ngModel.$modelValue === false) {
        if (val && confirm('sure want to check?')) {
          return val;
        } else {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(x);
          ngModel.$render();
          return x;
        }
      }

      if (ngModel.$viewValue === false && ngModel.$modelValue === true) {
        if (!val && confirm('sure want to uncheck?')) {
          return val;
        } else {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(!x);
          ngModel.$render();
          return !x;
        }
      }

    });

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in ng change function

```js
$scope.ConfirmChange = function () {
      var prevValue = !$scope.Checked;
      var newValue = $scope.Checked;

      if (prevValue) {
        $scope.report.IsMouldApplicable = prevValue;

        SwalAsk("Uncheck", "Are you sure for uncheck?", 'question', true, "Yes, confirm", function () {
          $scope.Checked = newValue;
        }, null, function () {
          $scopeChecked= prevValue;
        });
      } 
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<label class="selectcheckbox ml-3" >
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Checked" ng-change="ConfirmChange();" /><i></i>
              </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

```
input type="checkbox" ng-model="customer.isCompleted"
    ng-change="if(confirm('sure?')) sc.data.$save(customer)"
```

Directive way:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
            if(val && confirm('sure want to check?') ||
               !val && confirm('sure want to uncheck?'))
                return val;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response,

Here's what's happening, Easy Way Doesn't work.

The directive way is working when I press OK, but when I press cancel,
it throws the following console error,
"Error: Key isCompleted was undefined. Cannot pass undefined in JSON. Use null instead."
The view acts as if the checkbox was checked (the model is not changing though) Is there a way it can be setup so that the isCompleted does't become undefined and instead remain in the previous state of 'true' or 'false'?